# Where is erlang system configuration file(sys.config) is located when using homebrew install

Tags: erlang, homebrew

In the Erlang [config](http://erlang.org/doc/man/config.html) documentation, it says:

> When starting Erlang in embedded mode, it is assumed that exactly one system configuration file is used, named `sys.config`. This file is to be located in `$ROOT/releases/Vsn`, where `$ROOT` is the Erlang/OTP root installation directory and `Vsn` is the release version.

But I cannot find this file on my MacBook.

I am using `sudo find / -name 'sys.config'` but still cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you starting Erlang in **embedded** mode? No, you do not. The second thing `sys.config` is expected there so you have to provide it there. If you are using `erlang` in interactive mode you can provide config using `-config` parameter to `erl` command. Normally Erlang can start without `sys.config` only using application configs. Try `find /usr/lib -name '*.app'`. See `env` option there. I recommend you to read OTP Design Principles
User's Guide [8 Applications](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html).